# Android - Google Maps Timezone API - Milliseconds/UTC

Tags: android, google-maps, datetime

I am using retrofit 2 to call the google maps timezone rest API. Here is the URL my app submitted:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=33.4556535,-117.634454&timestamp=1484098782775&key=*KEY*

The timestamp comes from System.currentTimeMillis()

I get "Invalid Request" from google. Narrowing this down further indicates the only problem is the time stamp/milliseconds.

```
Here is a version of timestamp that works:
1331161200

See above the version of timestamp that does not work (from System.currentTimeMillis() is: 1484098782775
```

The "extra" 2 digits seem suspect?

In summary, is System.currentTimeMillis() not the correct epoch/timestamp/milliseconds value Google is expecting?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns (from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)) the difference, measured in **milliseconds**, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro), the Google Maps Time Zone API expects the `timestamp` parameter to be in **seconds** since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC:

> **timestamp** specifies the desired time as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

So, to solve your problem, just convert the returned milliseconds from `System.currentTimeMillis()` to secons to use it as the `timestamp` parameter for your request.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks very much Antonio. I appreciate your help.